# remove parent div if the input value is empty and show parent div if the input value is not empty?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove parent div if the input value is empty and show parent div if the input value is not empty?

the value of the input field is dynamic which means the value of it is the value of another input filed and I do this using javascript.

so far I haven't been able to show/hide the parent div for some reason. and I suspect the reason is because the value of the input field is dynamic which means the users are not typing anything  in that input field. they are typing in another input filed and the value of the dynamic input field  gets updated accordingly.

Here is what i have so far for show/hide the parent div:

HTML:

```
<div id="BOTTEXT2" class="secTxt">
<input type="text" class="sect2" id="sect2" style="border:none; background:none; " value="" size="12"  readonly="readonly"/>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById("sect2").value == ""){
document.getElementById("BOTTEXT2").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: You have to run that piece of code whenever you update the value

Comment: I can see only one input field in your above code, where is the other once which updates this field?

Comment: @mystic, because that is the div that I need to remove the parent div for according to its value.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in an event handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('sect2');
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
        document.getElementById('BOTTEXT2').style.display = (input.value ? 'block' : 'none');
    }, false);
};
```

This way, whenever you update the input, the div state changes accordingly.

Comment: this doesn't do anything. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work for you, but follow the solution.
I created another input type out of main div to simulate the situation.
I used jQuery. After that, you can set your css of your way.

HTML

```
<div id="BOTTEXT2" class="secTxt">
    <input type="text" class="sect2" id="sect2" style="border:none; background:none; " value="BSAU145D" size="12"  readonly="readonly"/>            
</div>
<input type="text" id="sect1">
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sect1').keyup(function(){
        if($('#sect1').val() == 'test') {
            $('#BOTTEXT2').css({'display':'none'});
        } else {
            $('#BOTTEXT2').css({'display':'block'});
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjX2L/)